# Can you always assume, without loss of generality, that the distance between any two points in a metric space is less than 1?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces

In Topology Without Tears, on page 274, there is a proof of the following claim:

Proposition. Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space. Then it is homeomorphic to a subspace of the cube $I^X$.

In the proof, it is stated that one can, without loss of generality, assume $d(a,b) <=  1$ for all $a$ and $b$ in $X$. At first I thought that maybe the reason for this was because $R^+$ is homeomorphic to $(0,1)$, but the interval in question is closed, not open, so the homeomorphism does not hold. Why, then, can we take $d(a,b) <=  1$? Can we do this for any metric space?

Answer (score 6):

Always? No. E.g. when you are interested in isometry. But if up to homeomorphism only then yes.

Consider any metric space $(X,d)$ and introduce a new metric on $X$:

$$d'(x,y)=\min\big(d(x,y), 1\big)$$

First of all note that $d'(x,y)\leq 1$. Furthermore a subset is open in $(X,d)$ if and only if it is open in $(X,d')$. Ergo the identity

$$id:X\to X$$
$$id(x)=x$$

is a homeomorphism between $(X,d)$ and $(X,d')$.